# Will all mass eventually decay, ending space-time but starting a new-space-time?

Tags: thermodynamics, spacetime, big-bang

I seem to recall learning from a TV programme (so there may be problems with this already!) that the 2nd law of thermodynamics provides that everything in the universe will at some point decay into massless particles. If so I'm assuming everything would simply wiz around at the speed of light. If that's true, then that would mean that time would effectively stop (or a least be irrelevant). Then if everything is no time away from each other..could that mean everything is in the same place (meaning space also effectively stops or at least becomes irrelevant). If so, could that trigger a singularity where everything in an infinitely small space, triggering an inflation/Big Bang/some kind of re-birth?

I'm very beginner physics - so I'm sure there are many potholes to this thread of logic - but I'd be interested to find out the errors in it - or (slim chance) any possible merits to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the mass decays, protons decay - very slowly - to positrons and neutral pions. The neutral pions decay (very fast) to photons, they are massive particles and also the positrons are massive.

The positrons and the electrons (proton and electron are there in the same number in the universe) annihillate into gamma photons. Also they are massive.

Sometimes also a little bit of neutrino is produced, furthermore the current Universe has a lot of neutrinos. Also they are massive, and except some rare cases, they don't decay. The overwhelming majority of the once produced neutrinos will exist forever.

The estimated half life of the protons is at least $10^{35}$ years. With sophisticated experiments it is around the border which can be already measured, but it was until now unsuccesful. Thus, we don't know for sure, that this whole proton decay really exist, although the experts are nearly sure in that.

What is known, if the proton decay exist, its half life is at least $10^{35}$ years. If it would be shorter, we could have already seen that. Compare this to the age of the Universe, which is around $10^{10}$ years. If the protons decay, they do this so slowly, that around a single proton decays in a liter water during the current age of the Universe.

What will happen to the Universe in such a long term, is unknown. Science is about the *reproducible experiments*. But you can't make an Universe in a laboratory, watch it $10^{35}$ year long, measure its properties and then write an article from that.

But there are quite good theory and models, which describe the processes and behavior of the past of the Universe, and these calculations can be extrapolated to the future. Thus, the whole thing is more as augury only in the sense, that this is the best what can be done.

On the current best knowledge, there is no such thing that the Universe will once end and a new Big Bang will happen. They say, it will expand forever. But note, really nobody knows.

Answer (score 1):

[The 2nd Law of Thermodynamics](https://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry/Thermodynamics/Laws_of_Thermodynamics/Second_Law_of_Thermodynamics) in effect says that the thermal energy in a closed system tends with passage of time to become unavailable for work.  In other words, entropy either increases or stays the same in a closed system.

In the Universe as a closed system, it's more probable that order would decay into randomness, than that randomness would organize itself without an available source of thermal energy to draw upon.

This has no effect upon the structure of space-time.  It just means that eventually it will become improbable that anything will measure space-time or will provide local curvature to space-time.  Considering only the 2nd Law of Thermodynamics, it is likely the Universe will become larger, colder, and more uniform than it is at present.